# Is the projection a multiple?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Say I have vectors $x, y$, then is $\text{proj }_x y $ a scalar multiple of $x$?

I have a book saying that it is, but I have no clue why this true. Is this really true?

Comment: What does the book say about it? Please share it.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $\textrm{proj}_xy\in\textrm{span}(x)$, so **yes**, this is true.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. What else could the projection be? It has to be an element of the subspace spanned by $y$, which consists precisely of the scalar multiples of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is true. You should check any definitions/formulas for the projection that you have.

In general, $$\operatorname{proj}_x y = \frac{\langle y,x\rangle }{\langle x,x\rangle } x$$
from which your claim is clear.